# Order by week, data between 2 years postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database table `transaction` with the following columns:

> date | mccg | us_amount | country |

Sample contents are:

```
08/10/2016 22:00:56 | 003 | 10  | UK
14/12/2016 19:26:34 | 004 | 30  | GER
18/02/2017 05:06:22 | 018 | 100 | UK
10/03/2016 14:52:45 | 018 | 25  | UK
12/03/2016 18:02:22 | 018 | 02  | UK
```

I want to get a result as follows:

```
year_month_week | us_amount|  country | mccg
2016-03-2       | 27       |  UK      |  018
2017-02-2       | 100      |  UK      |  01
```

I searched online for similar solutions but couldnt get any helpful ones.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT      year_month_week as (?),us_amount,country,mccg         
FROM        transaction
WHERE       country like 'UK' and mccg like '018'
GROUP BY    year_month_week
ORDER BY    year_month_week
```

But my problem is how to set year_month_week working, or whatever weekly format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char()`:

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-WW') as year_month_week,
       SUM(us_amount) as us_amount, country, mccg         
FROM transaction
WHERE country like 'UK' and mccg like '018'
GROUP BY year_month_week, country, mccg
ORDER BY year_month_week;
```

If you want other countries or mccgs, then remove the `WHERE` filtering.

Comment: One of the great solution. Thanks